# Collection View and Detail View Paging

Tags: ios, xcode, uicollectionview

I have been doing much reading and looking at app samples and am still unsure how to implement a collection view that pushes to a detail view with paging?

I am able to get a collection view to push to a static detail view (unfortunately without titles) and I can get paging working without a collection view but not both together!? I also need to take across a title as well which is an important part.

Please can someone help me with this as I may go insane soon :)

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just push another collection view controller with flow layout, horizontal scrolling direction, enabled `paging` property and set `itemSize` property of your layout to be full screen. Before pushing set content offset of this controller to be on a selected image. Try the following code. You should call `initWithCollectionViewLayout` to initialize your collection view.

```
-(id)initWithCollectionViewLayout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)layout {
if (self = [super initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout]) {
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout;
    layout.itemSize = self.collectionView.bounds.size;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
    self.collectionView.pagingEnabled = YES;

    // In order to see cells you can declare something like colors array in .h
    self.colors = @[[UIColor redColor], [UIColor greenColor], [UIColor blueColor]];
}
return self;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.shopNames.count;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:self.colors[indexPath.item]];

    return cell;
}
```

P.S. To set content offset use `[self.collectionView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(40, 0)];`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to all of this, how would I do that?